# How to preserve the order of columns in file from saveAsTextFile to match DataFrame's order?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to end up with the order of columns in the text file (after `saveAsTextFile`) to match the order of columns in the DataFrame.

```
DataFrame sourceRufFrame = sqlContext.sql(
  String.format("SELECT %s FROM SrcTempTable ORDER BY AddressID asc", columnsToChoose.toString()));

sourceRufFrame.toJavaRDD()
  .map(new TildaDelimiter())
  .coalesce(1, true)
  .saveAsTextFile(targetSrcFilePath);
```

Is there any option I can set?